# imap_search today

Tags: php

I do not think I am passing in the date correctly for imap_search()

```
$date = date("j F Y");

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ON "$date"' );
```

What is the correct way to form this argument? I want to retrieve the emails on the current date.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, just:

```
$date = date("j F Y");

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ON "'.$date.'"' );
```

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me.

```
$date = date("j-F-Y");

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ON "'.$date.'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it a little:

```
$date = date("j F Y");

$emails = imap_search($inbox,"ON \"{$date}\"");
```

You had `$date` inside a single quoted string, so no parsing was being done.

At least I think this is the problem!